# How to remove Environment Error in codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, windows-10, codeblocks, environment

I'm new in programming I've installed **codeblocks-17.12mingw** when I open the program it shows a Error message bellow

**Environment error** 
*Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for Microsoft Visual C++ Toolkit 2003.* 
[image: Please see the image]


I couldn't fixed the problem, could you please help me out how to solve the problem ? 

Thanks


**Note:** *My OS is windows 10 64 bit*.

Comment: I can't see the image. Can you paste it as text?

Comment: He already did that. It says ***Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for Microsoft Visual C++ Toolkit 2003.***

Comment: The exact message is:
 
"Environment error
Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for Microsoft Visual C++ Toolkit 2003"

Image link: https://ibb.co/sRvPpxV
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because there is no compiler in your computer or the path is not true. If there is no compiler, you can download minGW. If there is a compiler, the path may not be true. Go to `Settings > Compiler > Tool chain executibles > Compiler's installation directory` and check if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is solved with simple tricks** 

 
Try to go Settings->Compiler->Select "GNU gcc" from the drop down menu -> Then press "set as default" button.
Close the dialog with OK
Close codeblocks and restart it
Open codeblocks and try to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download a version of codeblocks with compiler included.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The install error persists with both. There is no "Select "GNU gcc"" choice in either ".exe's. I downloaded codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe and I can "Run" w/o issue. Aside the install error, codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe just did nothing running C++ from W3

Comment: how is this answer supposed to help OP? Imagine you were OP and you read this answer...